# MYSQL - Help with a more complicated Query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

`tbl_lists` and `tbl_houses`

Inside `tbl_lists` I have a field called HousesList - it contains the ID's for several houses in the following format:

```
1# 2# 4# 51# 3#
```

I need to be able to select the mysql fields from `tbl_houses` WHERE ID = any of those ID's in the list. 
More specifically, I need to `SELECT SUM(tbl_houses.HouseValue) WHERE tbl_houses.ID IN tbl_lists.HousesList` -- and I want to do this select to return the `SUM` for several rows in `tbl_lists`.

Anyone can help ?
 I'm thinking of how I can do this in a SINGLE query since I don't want to do any mysql `loops` (within PHP).

Comment: I am currently trying something like:

tbl_lists.HousesList LIKE CONCAT('% ', tbl_houses.ID,'#')

..not working lol... it only selects the first record in the list

Comment: Storing lists in fields is generally not a good idea. Can you change the schema, or is that outside of your control?

Comment: I store lists in fields to prevent the need for unique field names since my project is highly dynamic. Not going to change this. Don't worry I only do this for specific things which require more dynamic field names.

Comment: I got this working but it only selects the first result from tbl_houses:

SELECT * FROM tbl_houses WHERE (SELECT List FROM tbl_lists WHERE tbl_lists.ID = '123') LIKE CONCAT('% ', ID, '#')

Comment: I GOT THE ANSWER:

refer to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491970/msyql-why-does-this-query-only-select-a-single-row

Comment: I saw your other question. Why would you post a different variation of the same question twice. You could have updated your query in this thread as well?

Answer (score 0):

If your schema is really fixed, I'd do two queries:

`SELECT HousesList FROM tbl_lists WHERE ... (your conditions)`

In PHP, split the lists and create one array $houseIDs of IDs. Then run a second query:

`SELECT SUM(HouseValue) FROM tbl-Houses WHERE ID IN (`.join(", ", $houseIDs).`)`

I still suggest changing the schema into something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_lists (listID int primary key, ...)
CREATE TABLE tbl_lists_houses (listID int, houseID int)
CREATE TABLE tbl_houses (houseID int primary key, ...)
```

Then the query becomes trivial:

`SELECT SUM(h.HouseValue) FROM tbl_houses AS h, tbl_lists AS l, tbl_lists_houses AS lh WHERE l.listID = <your value> AND lh.listID = l.listID AND lh.houseID = h.houseID`

Storing lists in a single field really prevents you from doing anything useful with them in the database, and you'll be going back and forth between PHP and the database for everything. Also (no offense intended), "my project is highly dynamic" might be a bad excuse for "I have no requirements or design yet".

Comment: Thanks I will look into this. No I considered having a seperate table for each list storing them that way, however I will end up needing hundreds of tables just to store ids. It's not just tbl_lists_houses, but many more... tbl_lists_boats, etc. etc. and each table would require different field names too. Lists was much more efficient, but maybe I overlooked something. Anyway thanks again I'll look into this.

Comment: BTW I may end up not needing this query and just storing the SUMS separately since I need to avoid multiple query calls as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

normalise http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization